# Asp.Net 5 Nuget package error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I added VNext class library to ASp.Net 5 project, and I'm trying to add Nuget package "Npsql":

[image]

But it can't compile, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you add the dependency to all TFMs (`dnx451` and `dnxcore50`). Mostly sure,  `Npgsql` doesn't support `dnxcore50` (CoreCLR).

You have 3 solutions:

1. Remove `dnxcore50` completely
2. Move the dependency under `dnx451`
3. Use `#if DNX451` conditional compilation blocks in your code